# Contract lines are not getting expired in MS CRM 2013

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

We have multiple instances for our poject like Sandbox, Staging and Live. They are behaving differently on Contract lines.

In staging on the contract line end date, the lines are getting expired.

But this is not happening in Sandbox and live, what might be the reason?

And we observed that on the contract lines in Staging  the

Total Cases/Minutes is setting to 1 on expiring but this is not happening in PROD and Sandbox. And if we are manually placing it in there it is reseting it to ZERO.

Can any one say why this is happening..?

Thanks

Comment: (Is it 2011 or 2013 ? Tags don't match the title) Mandatory question: are you 101% sure customizations are exactly the same across all environments ? Since DEV does something that STAGE and PROD don't, triple-check no one changed anything (been there, done that...)

Comment: hi Alex,
It is 2013, and we have gone through the customizations they look same in Staging and Live.

Comment: Check DEV too..

Comment: We have checked the CRM server internal activities and we found all the asynchronous calls are failing in DEV. Our sysops did something in server and it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the asynchronous activities in CRM Service/Server, they are getting failed because of some reason.